# same page renders differently from VS and prod server

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET webpage.
If I run it via VS server, I get a first rendering (localhost screenshot).
When I upload the same code on the prod IIS server, and browse the same page on the same browser of the same computer with the same parameters,
I get a very different rendering (IIS prod screenshot).

What can be the cause of this?

For instance, the top left image is apparently rendered with a different size. This is not something I would have expected?????

Code of the page if it helps (I don't think so).

```
<div class="container-fluid" >
        <div class="row" style="background-color:#002337;">
            <div class="col-md-3" >
              <table id="Tableau_01" width="801px" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td    align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#002337">
                            <img src="images/2016_page_html/Elements-pageHTML-Haut.png" alt="" width="220" height="200">
                        </td>
                    </tr>



                    <tr>
                        <td width="301" height="400" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#002337" style="margin-left: 50px;font-size: 0.80em; color: #FFF; font-family: News Gothic Medium, Helvetica, Verdana, Arial; line-height: 1.28em;">

                            <p style="margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 0px;margin-left: 50px;">
                                <asp:Image ID="i_imgLogoBleu" runat="server" Width="250px" />
                            </p>
                            <h3>
                            <p style="margin-left: 50px;">
                                <asp:Label ID="i_lblAdresse" runat="server" />
                            </p>
                            </h3>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9 "   style="background-color: #002337;height:600px;margin-top:50px" >

            <form id="form1" class="form-horizontal" runat="server"  >
                      <div class="" align="left" >

                                <div class="col-md-12" >
                                <telerik:RadScriptManager  runat="server" ID="RadScriptManager1"></telerik:RadScriptManager>
                                <telerik:RadMediaPlayer ID="RadMediaPlayer1" runat="server" AutoPlay="True" Height="500px" Width="80%" Source="~/videos/video.mp4" BorderStyle="None" Skin="Silk" StartVolume="80" HDSource="~/videos/video.mp4">
                                </telerik:RadMediaPlayer>
                                    </div>
                          </div>
                </form>
           </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row"  style="background-color:#ffffff;"  >
            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <p style="padding-left: 15px; padding-top: 25px; font-family: Garamond, Georgia, Helvetica, Verdana; font-size: 2em; color: #002337;line-height: 1.2em; font-weight: bold;">
                    <asp:Label ID="i_lblContenu" runat="server" />
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <img src="images/2016_page_html/Elements-pageHTML-Bas.png" width="120" height="100" alt="logo_bas" name="logo_bas" id="logo_bas">
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Thx in advance for sharing your knowledge.

A 
[image: localhost]

[image: IIS prod]

Edit: the image difference does not look so obvious into the post. Do open both images into a new tab to really see the differences.
Main differences are:

- size of the top left image
- both image have a top blue frame and a bottom white frame. But on the localhost version, the white frame's height = the bottom image's height. On the prod version, the height is much bigger than this.

Comment: Is either `localhost` or prod domain part of some sort of special case domain. Like IE:s `Compatibility view`..?

Comment: Have you compared the computed CSS rules in the browsers dev tools (f12) and tried to find out if and why those CSS rules were computed differently? Does the website get rendered differently across all major browser vendors?

Comment: @Marco : good point! The differences only occur with Chrome. Same rendering with IE and Firefox.

Comment: @Marco : I checked the computed CSS rules in chrome. Indeed there seems to be some differences.
localhost mentions 1300.400 * 750 dimensions.
IIS prod page mentions 1680 * 930 (which is my actual resolution).
Not sure why this is different though????

Comment: Edit: Could you post your `<head>` section as well?